# Custom objectset extension methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, extension-methods

I have tried Googling strings like "c# ef objectset extension methods" but I suppose I'm using the wrong terms here, because I can't find anything relevant.

What I would like to know is how I add a custom extenstionmethod that I can use on my database context:

```
context.TABLE.MyMethod(...
```

I assume that there are a lot of SO threads covering this, but I can't find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static class YourExtensions
{
    public static void MyMethod<T>(this DbSet<T> table)
       where T: class // this constraint is required because DbSet<T> have it
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Here is MSDN article on [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't `DbSet` be `IEnumerable` though?

Comment: @Johan that depends on whether you want this method to be applied to `DbSet` only, or to any enumerable

Comment: @Johan it is generic now :) You can use it with any table

Comment: Yeah just noticed. I though you wanted me to switch <T> to the actual type at first :). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Johan I made a small update - you need a constraint here for generic parameter. It should be a class

Comment: Could you explain what it does? It seems to compile fine without it.

Comment: Ah, I guess it's limiting to allow class-types only?

Comment: @Johan yes, but without this constraint you can't use `DbSet<T>`. Because same constraint defined for it's parameter `T`. If you are extending `IEnumerable<T>` then you don't need this constraint

Comment: `public static void MyMethod<T>(this IEnumerable<T> table) where T : class {}` gives me the error "identifier expected". What did I miss? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31767/discussion-between-lazyberezovsky-and-johan)